# How to make an answer using an existing work acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers

When there is a question which is not related to any existing fiction but the question asker's own creation. If they ask in search of some element X to include in their universe and list
criteria for X.

I then want to answer something along the lines of "In the *Space Hike* universe X was included in this and that way and it obeyed the following rules" or "In the *Ruler of the Bracelets* X worked but was based on Y".

In general describe how the same (or similar) element works in an existing body of fiction.

What would be a good way of making sure the answer is good and on-topic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would we support expanding existing (fictional) worlds?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/would-we-support-expanding-existing-fictional-worlds)

Comment: @VogonPoet no, I'm my query does not pertain to *questions* about existing. world. It's using it in *answers* using existing world. The question would be in search of *something* and give out the criteria as normal. And I was wondering if how to take an existing element fom fiction in order to form *an answer*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the following two steps are needed to ensure the quality of the answer:

1. Provide proper reference, detailing out the specifics of the case
2. Explain why the referred example is applicable to the question

Example:

> A magical entity has created an artifact which contains and amplifies all the power of the entity and allows controlling the bearers of other artifacts related to the first one. How can I balance this feature with the possibility of destroying it?

A poor answer would be:

> The Lord of the Rings has a similar element, check it out!

A better answer would be:

> In [The Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings) Sauron has crafted a ring with similar features: it amplifies its powers and contains them. Moreover, it allows controlling the other rings and their bearers. However, to use the ring, Sauron has to wear it. That's what allows Frodo to take the Ring to Mount Doom and destroy it. You can use a similar mechanism in your story.

Comment: In other words, same as with any other answer: if non-obvious, explain how it is an answer to the question, and either way, make sure you *answer the question* in such a way that the answer can stand on its own in response to the question.